# Ask and answer GitHub / Domain question for duplicate or wiki

Tags: discussion

We have been getting a lot of GitHub / Domain Name questions lately. After looking at a few various answers, it seems like the process is pretty straight forward regardless of the registrar though it can vary slightly.

Perhaps we should ask and answer a question so that we can use it for a duplicate or wiki.

[Edit]

Okay. Perhaps I should be asking more questions in what is a rudderless question.

What is the normal or best process for something like this?

Should I just post a question that gets changed somehow?

Who can answer this question best?

My fear is that if I ask the question, it becomes just another question in the long list of questions. What I am envisioning is a question is asked and answered with authority and detail enough to reference over and over with room for other answers specific to certain providers.

My last question is this.

Are there any volunteers to take on the task of creating as much of an authoritative answer as can exist? It may require some research that I am not able to take on at this time. I will post the question.

Comment: I will help to answer the wiki question as much I can. I know how custom domain works with github pages.

Comment: @Goyllo Way major cool dude!! Later today I will post the question. I got to bed at 5am and up a 10. I have a few things to do then catch up on my sleep. After that, then maybe my brain will work right. ;-) Cheers!!